# How to setup multiple Timer in Swift3

Tags: timer, swift3

I'm trying to setup a series of uploading work to the server. I want to send the data package one by one, so I want to set up a certain time interval as waiting period between each upload job. So I tried to use the static method in the Timer class:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false, block: { (Timer) in
//Upload 1st package
print("The 1st package upload!") 
}

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 20.0, repeats: false, block: { (Timer) in
//Upload 2nd package
print("The 2nd package upload!")  
}

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30.0, repeats: false, block: { (Timer) in
//Upload 3rd package
print("The 3rd package upload!")  
}

//....And so on....
```

The purpose is to allow a 10 sec period between each timer triggering point. But the problem is only the first timer waiting period of 10 sec is observed, while the following up jobs in the later timers just fired off right after the completion of the first upload task, as indicated by the timing when each print job show up. Can anyone help me understand why this happens? And suggestions for solving the issue?

Thank you very much!

Paul

Comment: Wait, do you want the uploads 10 seconds apart, or 10 seconds after the completion of the previous upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All 3 of these timers are starting at essentially the same time. To get it to work similar to what you show, you'll have to nest the timers, such that timer `n` trigger timer `n+1`, nested as many times as necessary. However, this works out to be a really clunky solution.

Instead, it's better to have one timer that repeats.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30.0, repeats: true) { timer in
    let packagesUploaded = (timer.userInfo ?? 0) + 1
    timer.userInfo = packagesUploaded

    print("Uploaded package #\(packagesUploaded)!")

    if packagesUploaded == 10 { timer.invalidate() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploads are asynchronous. Thus, the problem is that you are not *waiting* for the upload to complete. You are just running these timers completely independently of any other reality. You are setting them all at once and then they just fire when their time comes.

So, for example, if an upload take 30 seconds, the second and third timers will fire while the first upload is still in progress.

If you want to wait ten seconds after an upload completes, you need to start a ten-second timer *in the delegate method* of the upload that tells you that it has completed.